# how to bring a background task to foreground in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, task-queue

Currently I have tasks running in background. After the tasks are done executing I need to show output. How do I do this in Google App Engine?

Once the tasks are done the only thing I can do is create another task which is supposed to show output or is there any other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't "bring a task to the foreground" -- it is a webserver.  The server responds to requests from the client.

But, you have a couple choices to accomplish something similar:

1. Use the [Channel API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/) to send the client notice that the work is finished, or a even the results of the processing.
2. Write status info to [memcache](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/) or the [datastore](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/) and poll from the client to determine when the work is finished.

Comment: Option #2 is probably the most straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work directly as you describe it.

Once a background task is started, it's a background task for its entire existence.  If you want to return some information from the background task to the user, you'll have to add it to the datastore, and have a foreground handler check the datastore for that information.

You may also be able to use the Channel API to have a background task send messages directly to the browser, but I'm not sure if this will work or not (I haven't tried it).

If you give a little more information about exactly what you're trying to accomplish I can try to give more details about how to get it done.